# How do I add a sorted array of objects within a mongo aggregate pipeline?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm using a mongo Aggregate pipeline, to transform documents.  The why is simple enough:  make the documents easier to read from.

The documents start off looking something like this:

workouts...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59ccd28338c8f273346b1997"
  },
  "updateAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506952456789"
    }
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506678599417"
    }
  },
  "name": "Strength 1",
  "phase": {
    "$oid": "59ccd1a738c8f273346b1988"
  },
  "primer": {
    "$oid": "5df7625ce69199d3fa3c4746"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "_partition": "PUBLIC"
}
```

which is little more than a placeholder: almost all the information that comprises a workout is held in other collections, tied together by this documents' _id.

1. do that first lookup^ to get the primer (aka warmup) reference.
2. use that primer ref to get the warmup, by looking up that reference in two other collections and joining the outputs *(I won't expand on those, as I do that bit fine already)*
3. then head to a fourth collection, and use the original object Id to get another inter-connector type document, with data like this:

plans...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b199c"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506597063143"
    }
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506597063143"
    }
  },
  "workout": {
    "$oid": "59ccd28338c8f273346b1997"
  },
  "exercise": {
    "$oid": "59cccdc938c8f273346b1985"
  },
  "code": "A1",
  "weekOne": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b1998"
  },
  "weekTwo": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b1999"
  },
  "weekThree": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b199a"
  },
  "weekFour": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b199b"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "_partition": "PUBLIC"
}
```

4. then use the exercise-Id on a fifth collection to get the exercise info, which is stored like this...

exercises...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59cccdc938c8f273346b1985"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1579906674667"
    }
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506594249199"
    }
  },
  "name": "DB Split Squat",
  "timing": "3-0-1-0",
  "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/KgPxYpvHUe8",
  "cues": "Keep your chest tall and shoulders back.\nAs you descend, shoulders and hips should stay in a line (don't lean forward).\nHips should go straight down and straight up.\nYou should have an approximately 90-degree angle for both knees.\nBack knee should come close, but not touch, the ground.",
  "__v": 0,
  "is_weighted": true,
  "_partition": "PUBLIC"
}
```

5. and use the "weekOne" etc object IDs in a sixth collection to retrieve the structure (reps & sets) of the workout.  Data for that looks like this:

programmings...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59ccd8c738c8f273346b1999"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506597063068"
    }
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1506597063068"
    }
  },
  "sets": 3,
  "setRest": 30,
  "reps": "8-10",
  "repRest": null,
  "supersetRest": null,
  "exercise": {
    "$oid": "59cccdc938c8f273346b1985"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "_partition": "PUBLIC"
}
```

We want to generate new documents that contain all the information needed for a given workout, in one document.  *(I am sure there are various pros/cons of alternative approaches, however this decision has been made; my job is not to debate it, but to implement it :) )*

## My Current Aggregate Pipeline

```
[
  {
    // NOTE limiter is just for testing!
    // remove when ready to go live!
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    // Fetch the Warmup top-level fields
    $lookup: {
      from: "primers",
      localField: "primer",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 1,
            show_reminder: 1,
            note: 1,
            exercises: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "warmup",
    },
  },
  {
    // squish the warmup 1-element array to an object
    $unwind: {
      path: "$warmup",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
    },
  },
  {
    // fetch the warmup exercise info
    $lookup: {
      from: "primer_plans",
      localField: "primer",
      foreignField: "primer",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "exercises",
            localField: "exercise",
            foreignField: "_id",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  name: 1,
                  cues: 1,
                  videoUrl: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
            as: "exercise",
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            order: 1,
            exercise: 1,
            repText: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$exercise",
        },
      ],
      as: "warmup.exercises",
    },
  },
  {
    // add arrays to populate later
    $addFields:
      // also add references to og docs, in case needed
      {
        overview: {
          supersetted: [],
          nonSupersetted: [],
        },
        workout: {
          supersetted: [],
          nonSupersetted: [],
        },
        references: {
          usedInPhase: {
            _id: "$phase",
          },
          warmup: {
            _id: "$primer",
          },
          ogWorkout: "$_id",
        },
      },
  },
  {
    // Fetch the Workout fields (and expand exercises)
    $lookup:
      // this is used to fill the non-supersetted version
      {
        from: "plans",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "workout",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "exercises",
              localField: "exercise",
              foreignField: "_id",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    name: 1,
                    cues: 1,
                    videoUrl: 1,
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "exercise",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$exercise" },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "programmings",
              localField: "weekOne",
              foreignField: "_id",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    sets: 1,
                    setRest: 1,
                    reps: 1,
                    repRest: 1,
                  },
                },
                {
                  $addFields: {
                    week: 1,
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "weekOne",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$weekOne" },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "programmings",
              localField: "weekTwo",
              foreignField: "_id",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    sets: 1,
                    setRest: 1,
                    reps: 1,
                    repRest: 1,
                  },
                },
                {
                  $addFields: {
                    week: 2,
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "weekTwo",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$weekTwo" },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "programmings",
              localField: "weekThree",
              foreignField: "_id",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    sets: 1,
                    setRest: 1,
                    reps: 1,
                    repRest: 1,
                  },
                },
                {
                  $addFields: {
                    week: 3,
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "weekThree",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$weekThree" },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "programmings",
              localField: "weekFour",
              foreignField: "_id",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    sets: 1,
                    setRest: 1,
                    reps: 1,
                    repRest: 1,
                  },
                },
                {
                  $addFields: {
                    week: 4,
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "weekFour",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$weekFour" },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 0,
              code: 1,
              superset: { $substr: ["$code", 0, 1] },
              supersetIndex: { $substr: ["$code", 1, 1] },
              exercise: "$exercise",
              valuesThatVaryByWeek: [
                "$weekOne",
                "$weekTwo",
                "$weekThree",
                "$weekFour",
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "workout.nonSupersetted",
      },
  },
  {
    /**
     * newField: The new field name.
     * expression: The new field expression.
     */
    $addFields: {
      "workout.allWorkoutIndices": {
        $map: {
          input: "$workout.nonSupersetted",
          in: {
            $getField: {
              field: "code",
              input: "$$this",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    // clone to workout supersetted
    $set: {
      "workout.supersetted": "$workout.nonSupersetted",
    },
  },
  {
    // add the warmup name to the references
    $lookup: {
      from: "primers",
      localField: "primer",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "references.warmup.name",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$references.warmup.name",
    },
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_partition",
      "__v",
      "createdAt",
      "updateAt",
      "phase",
      "primer",
    ],
  },
  {
    // output to programData.workoutsTester
    $out: {
      db: "programData",
      coll: "workoutsTester",
    },
  },
]
```

## Current output

The new workout document now looks like...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59ccd28338c8f273346b1997"
  },
  "name": "Strength 1",
  "warmup": {
    "name": "Lower Body Lifting",
    "show_reminder": true,
    "note": "",
    "exercises": [
      {
        "order": 1,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Frog Squat",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/zZDq6OejYBM",
          "cues": "A great hamstring stretch and hip mobility focused exercise"
        },
        "repText": "5-8 reps"
      },
      {
        "order": 2,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Frog Squat with Reach",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/Kem3YR2Fic4",
          "cues": "Different from the standard Frog Squat!\nMore of a full body movement challenge,\nLess stretch on the hamstrings & hip-hinge,\nMore challenging to thoracic spine mobility"
        },
        "repText": "5-8 reps"
      },
      {
        "order": 3,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Five point Lunge",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/bBdSuretuHY",
          "cues": ""
        },
        "repText": "Three reps each leg"
      },
      {
        "order": 4,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Three point SLDL",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/r1hPMviYbLQ",
          "cues": ""
        },
        "repText": "Three reps each leg"
      },
      {
        "order": 5,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Backwards Spiderman",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/drHorMgQBWM",
          "cues": ""
        },
        "repText": "If you have time add this full-body mobility drill"
      },
      {
        "order": 6,
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Walking Bow and Arrow",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/7MeaaZ8pRNQ",
          "cues": ""
        },
        "repText": "If you have time add this full-body mobility drill"
      }
    ]
  },
  "overview": {
    "supersetted": [],
    "nonSupersetted": []
  },
  "workout": {
    "nonSupersetted": [
      {
        "code": "A1",
        "superset": "A",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "DB Split Squat",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/KgPxYpvHUe8",
          "cues": "Keep your chest tall and shoulders back.\nAs you descend, shoulders and hips should stay in a line (don't lean forward).\nHips should go straight down and straight up.\nYou should have an approximately 90-degree angle for both knees.\nBack knee should come close, but not touch, the ground."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "A2",
        "superset": "A",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Cable Pull-Through",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/2lXOIeiWYk4",
          "cues": "Feet are slightly wider than shoulder width. Knees are bent about 10 degrees.\nReach back between your legs with the rope attachment.\nUse your glutes to push your hips forward and stand up."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "B1",
        "superset": "B",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Semi-supinated grip Pull-up",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/R-j7IvquHwE",
          "cues": "\"Semi supinated\" means that your palms are facing one another. If you do not have a bar that allows for this, use a supinated grip (palms toward you).\nKeep your chest up.\nSqueeze shoulder blades together at the top of the movement.\nIf you do not have an assisted chin­-up machine, you can use a lat pulldown instead."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "4-6",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "4-6",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "C1",
        "superset": "C",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Stability Ball Hip Raise to Bridge",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/MEqwmz-nfVo",
          "cues": "Squeeze the glutes to get the hips off the floor.\nKeeping the glutes tight, bring the ball in toward you forming a 90 degree angle of the knees."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "C2",
        "superset": "C",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Bow and Arrow",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/Fq9Jlz261m4",
          "cues": "If you imagine an archer, you will naturally do this exercise correctly.\nStand up tall.\nKeep the elbow of the pulling arm up.\nSqueeze the shoulder blades together during the iso hold."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "B2",
        "superset": "B",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "One-Arm Semi-sup' Grip Incline DB Bench",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/tkPqct_J338",
          "cues": "Hold a dumbbell only in one hand while performing this exercise.\nEngage the core to resist rotation."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "allWorkoutIndices": [
      "A1",
      "A2",
      "B1",
      "C1",
      "C2",
      "B2"
    ],
    "supersetted": [
      {
        "code": "A1",
        "superset": "A",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "DB Split Squat",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/KgPxYpvHUe8",
          "cues": "Keep your chest tall and shoulders back.\nAs you descend, shoulders and hips should stay in a line (don't lean forward).\nHips should go straight down and straight up.\nYou should have an approximately 90-degree angle for both knees.\nBack knee should come close, but not touch, the ground."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "A2",
        "superset": "A",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Cable Pull-Through",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/2lXOIeiWYk4",
          "cues": "Feet are slightly wider than shoulder width. Knees are bent about 10 degrees.\nReach back between your legs with the rope attachment.\nUse your glutes to push your hips forward and stand up."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "B1",
        "superset": "B",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Semi-supinated grip Pull-up",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/R-j7IvquHwE",
          "cues": "\"Semi supinated\" means that your palms are facing one another. If you do not have a bar that allows for this, use a supinated grip (palms toward you).\nKeep your chest up.\nSqueeze shoulder blades together at the top of the movement.\nIf you do not have an assisted chin­-up machine, you can use a lat pulldown instead."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "4-6",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "4-6",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "C1",
        "superset": "C",
        "supersetIndex": "1",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Stability Ball Hip Raise to Bridge",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/MEqwmz-nfVo",
          "cues": "Squeeze the glutes to get the hips off the floor.\nKeeping the glutes tight, bring the ball in toward you forming a 90 degree angle of the knees."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "C2",
        "superset": "C",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "Bow and Arrow",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/Fq9Jlz261m4",
          "cues": "If you imagine an archer, you will naturally do this exercise correctly.\nStand up tall.\nKeep the elbow of the pulling arm up.\nSqueeze the shoulder blades together during the iso hold."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 30,
            "reps": "10-12",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "B2",
        "superset": "B",
        "supersetIndex": "2",
        "exercise": {
          "name": "One-Arm Semi-sup' Grip Incline DB Bench",
          "videoUrl": "https://youtu.be/tkPqct_J338",
          "cues": "Hold a dumbbell only in one hand while performing this exercise.\nEngage the core to resist rotation."
        },
        "valuesThatVaryByWeek": [
          {
            "sets": 2,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 1
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "8-10",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 2
          },
          {
            "sets": 3,
            "setRest": 60,
            "reps": "6-8",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 3
          },
          {
            "sets": null,
            "setRest": null,
            "reps": "",
            "repRest": null,
            "week": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "references": {
    "usedInPhase": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "59ccd1a738c8f273346b1988"
      }
    },
    "warmup": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5df7625ce69199d3fa3c4746"
      },
      "name": {
        "name": "Lower Body Lifting"
      }
    },
    "ogWorkout": {
      "$oid": "59ccd28338c8f273346b1997"
    }
  }
}
```

which is much closer, but still not quite there.

## My current questions

The workout above, is, stripping out all the extra bumpf, basically this:

```
{
  ...,
  notSupersetted: [
    { superset: "a", supersetIndex: 1, <other data> },
    { superset: "c", supersetIndex: 1, ...},
    { superset: "a", supersetIndex: 2, ...},
    { superset: "c", supersetIndex: 2, ...},
    { superset: "b", supersetIndex: 2, ...},
    { superset: "b", supersetIndex: 1, ...}
  ],
  supersetted: []
  ...
}
```

I need to:

1. find a way to add an index-ordering to notSupersetted. e.g. although they are listed as [a-1, c-1, a-2, c-2, b-2, b-1 ] these exercises should actually be done in alpha-numeric order, ie [ a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 ].  How do I generate a workout index for them?
2. populate the `supersetted` field, which is basically just a rearrangement of the non-supersetted field in this form...

```
{
  ...,
  notSupersetted: [ <as before> ],
  supersetted: [
    {
      superset: "A",
      elements: [
        { index: 1, <other data> },
        { index: 2, ... }
      ]
    },
    {
      superset: "B",
      elements: [
        { index: 1, ...},
        { index: 2, ... }
      ]
    },
    {
      superset: "C",
      elements: [
        { index: 1, ...},
        { index: 2, ...}
      ]
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of syntax. It would be more helpful if you can give us sample json documents so that we might figure out some syntax that work for you.

Comment: ooops didn't realise I couldn't post code directly in comments.  Hmnm.  I'll go update my the main post instead...

Comment: there you go @ray I've added the documents I'm working and the aggregate pipeline I've currently got to the original post.